# how to load a SolverResults object with bad status

Tags: python, pyomo, ipopt

I am using pyomo with IPOPT solver to solve an optimization problem.
I am facing an error "Cannot  load a SolverResults object with bad status". I would like to load the results anyway, I tried to set a 'max_iter' but it didn't work. Is there anyway I can do that?